# Handling backend validation errors in react-final-form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, react-final-form, final-form

how can I handle submission errors (submitErrors) returned from backend with dot-notation structure?

Example JSON response:

```
{
  "username": "Username is already taken",
  "interests": "Add 3 interests at least",
  "interests.0": "Type minimum 3 characters.."
}
```

"Interests" is FieldArray of strings. I want to show up both errors - for field array - an general error and for first error (0 index) in array.

It's not possible with default final-form approach because it requires to send something like this:

```
{
  "interests": [
    0 => "Type minimum 3 characters.."
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to force final-form to take error message by field name (dot-notation / flat errors array structure i.e.:
"interests.0": "error msg",
"attributes.0.name":"error msg") ?

Comment: Can you show a sandbox like the submission errors example where this is not working for arrays?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Below is an example with form and simulated backend error response.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1oz5ooq7l7

Comment: CustomError component resolves my problem for now, but it looks like a workaround ;)

Comment: What about this? All I did was put an undefined check for submitErrors on line 58. https://codesandbox.io/s/kokl0k13r5 Or does this side-step your intent?

Comment: Of course you are right, that was an oversight on my part :)
I removed Field component dependency from CustomError component because FormSpy has also "touched" array with meta. It should be now more efficient.
https://codesandbox.io/s/m9jxmwol99